# Insert row and col label when dumping matrix data to text file in python

Tags: python, numpy

I want to insert labels to col and row. like below.

```
    x   y   z
a   1   3   4
b   4   3   2
```

Actually I could do to add header like below.

```
import numpy as np
row_label = ["a", "b"]
col_label = ["x", "y", "z"]
data = np.array([[1,3,4], [4,3,2]])
np.savetxt("out.csv", data, header=",".join(["x", "y", "z"]), delimiter=",", fmt="%.0f", comments='')
```

out.csv

```
x,y,z
1,3,4
4,3,2
```

But how do I also add a column label?

Comment: Check out this related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9912647/python-numpy-save-array-with-column-and-row-titles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
row_label = ["a", "b"]
col_label = ["x", "y", "z"]
data = np.array([[1,3,4], [4,3,2]])
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=row_label, columns=col_label)
df.to_csv(r'temp.csv', sep='\t')
```

temp.csv

```
    x   y   z
a   1   3   4
b   4   3   2
```

Comment: YOUR ARE MY HERO!